# Table content is jumping when resizing

Tags: macos, nsscrollview

This problem just occurs in Mac OX 10.6 (10.7, 10.8 isnot).
The problem is recorded in the movie clip:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRyPSkgh5HY
Are there any solution? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have got some information here http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Jul/msg00734.html but the completed solution. I tried to contact the author. However, I cannot reach him

Comment: This problem only happend when using CALayer.In my work, I must use the CALayer.

Comment: Are there any people who have experience abou this problem. Please share. Thanks

Comment: Are there any people know why the problem happen?